# Adding a column to count consecutive weeks an specific condition happens

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df and I am looking to add the column "Desired Outcome" that will count the number of consecutive weeks a promotion_type is active in a specific store for an specific product code.

Any hints on how to move forward?

| store_code | product_code | date | promotion_type | Desired Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222 | 2021-01-03 | Promo descuento | 1 |
| 1 | 222 | 2021-02-28 | Promo cabecera | 1 |
| 1 | 232 | 2021-03-21 | Promo multicompra | 1 |
| 1 | 296 | 2021-01-17 | Promo descuento | 1 |
| 1 | 296 | 2021-01-24 | Promo descuento | 2 |
| 1 | 296 | 2021-01-31 | Promo descuento | 3 |
| 1 | 296 | 2021-02-07 | Promo descuento | 4 |
| 1 | 382 | 2021-02-07 | Promo descuento | 1 |
| 1 | 608 | 2021-01-10 | Promo descuento | 1 |
| 1 | 608 | 2021-01-17 | Promo descuento | 2 |
| 1 | 612 | 2021-01-03 | Promo descuento | 1 |
| 1 | 612 | 2021-01-31 | Promo descuento | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the question, this should solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

def add_desired_outcome(df):
    # Group the data by store_code, product_code, and promotion_type
    grouped = df.groupby(['store_code', 'product_code', 'promotion_type'])['date']
    
    # Calculate the difference in days between consecutive dates within each group
    date_diff = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days)
    
    # Check if the difference is not equal to 7 (i.e. not consecutive weeks)
    not_consecutive = date_diff.ne(7)
    
    # Calculate the cumulative sum within each group to create unique groups for consecutive weeks
    consecutive_groups = not_consecutive.groupby(level=0).cumsum()
    
    # Calculate the cumulative count within each group and add 1 to get the desired outcome
    desired_outcome = consecutive_groups.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1)
    
    # Add the desired outcome column to the DataFrame
    df['Desired Outcome'] = desired_outcome
    
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's copy the data we're going to use to another dataframe. Let's also create a column of zeros, to be used later:

```
>>> df_data = df[["date", "product_code", "promotion_type"]].copy()
>>> df_data["zeros"] = 0

         date  product_code     promotion_type  zeros
0  2021-01-03           222    Promo descuento      0
1  2021-02-28           222     Promo cabecera      0
2  2021-03-21           232  Promo multicompra      0
3  2021-01-17           296    Promo descuento      0
4  2021-01-24           296    Promo descuento      0
5  2021-01-31           296    Promo descuento      0
6  2021-02-07           296    Promo descuento      0
7  2021-02-07           382    Promo descuento      0
8  2021-01-10           608    Promo descuento      0
9  2021-01-17           608    Promo descuento      0
10 2021-01-03           612    Promo descuento      0
11 2021-01-31           612    Promo descuento      0
```

To make it easy to calculate the difference between the rows, let's convert the `"promotion_type"` column to numbers:

```
>>> df_data["promotion_type"] = df_data["promotion_type"].rank(method='dense')

         date  product_code  promotion_type  zeros
0  2021-01-03           222             2.0      0
1  2021-02-28           222             1.0      0
2  2021-03-21           232             3.0      0
3  2021-01-17           296             2.0      0
4  2021-01-24           296             2.0      0
5  2021-01-31           296             2.0      0
6  2021-02-07           296             2.0      0
7  2021-02-07           382             2.0      0
8  2021-01-10           608             2.0      0
9  2021-01-17           608             2.0      0
10 2021-01-03           612             2.0      0
11 2021-01-31           612             2.0      0
```

Since you want to do this operation *per product*, you will need to use `groupby`. Then, we can `diff()` this to get the difference between consecutive rows in a group.

```
>>> groups = df_data.groupby("product_code")
>>> group_diff = groups.diff()

      date  promotion_type  zeros
0      NaT             NaN    NaN
1  56 days            -1.0    0.0
2      NaT             NaN    NaN
3      NaT             NaN    NaN
4   7 days             0.0    0.0
5   7 days             0.0    0.0
6   7 days             0.0    0.0
7      NaT             NaN    NaN
8      NaT             NaN    NaN
9   7 days             0.0    0.0
10     NaT             NaN    NaN
11 28 days             0.0    0.0
```

Now, notice that we want to increment the value of `df["Desired Outcome"]` for only those rows where `group_diff["date"]` is `7 days` and `group_diff["promotion_type"]` is zero. Let's set the `zeros` column of the `df_data` for these rows to one:

```
>>> filt = (group_diff["date"] == pd.Timedelta(7, 'd')) & (group_diff["promotion_type"] == 0)
>>> df_data.loc[filt, "zeros"] = 1

         date  product_code  promotion_type  zeros
0  2021-01-03           222             2.0      0
1  2021-02-28           222             1.0      0
2  2021-03-21           232             3.0      0
3  2021-01-17           296             2.0      0
4  2021-01-24           296             2.0      1
5  2021-01-31           296             2.0      1
6  2021-02-07           296             2.0      1
7  2021-02-07           382             2.0      0
8  2021-01-10           608             2.0      0
9  2021-01-17           608             2.0      1
10 2021-01-03           612             2.0      0
11 2021-01-31           612             2.0      0
```

Finally, let's group `df_data` again, this time taking the cumulative sum of all groups:

```
>>> desired_outcome = df_data[["product_code", "zeros"]].groupby("product_code").cumsum()

    zeros
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       1
5       2
6       3
7       0
8       0
9       1
10      0
11      0
```

Notice that this is the desired outcome we need, except we need to add one:

```
>>> df["Desired Outcome"] = desired_outcome + 1
```

which leaves us with the desired result:

```
    store_code  product_code       date     promotion_type  Desired Outcome
0            1           222 2021-01-03    Promo descuento                1
1            1           222 2021-02-28     Promo cabecera                1
2            1           232 2021-03-21  Promo multicompra                1
3            1           296 2021-01-17    Promo descuento                1
4            1           296 2021-01-24    Promo descuento                2
5            1           296 2021-01-31    Promo descuento                3
6            1           296 2021-02-07    Promo descuento                4
7            1           382 2021-02-07    Promo descuento                1
8            1           608 2021-01-10    Promo descuento                1
9            1           608 2021-01-17    Promo descuento                2
10           1           612 2021-01-03    Promo descuento                1
11           1           612 2021-01-31    Promo descuento                1
```